# How to find all <a> elements and add a class to them using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to find all `a` elements within `.paginate` and add a class to them.

I currently have:

```
$('#search_result').html('<span class="ajax-loader">Please wait ...</span>')
                   .load('/search/ajax-search',$("#search-panel").serialize())
                   .find('.paginate p a')
                   .addClass('click_paginate');
```

but no luck.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="paginate clearfix">
    <p>
        <strong>1</strong>
        <a href="/search/ajax-search/P20">2</a>
        <a href="/search/ajax-search/P40">3</a>
        <a href="/search/ajax-search/P20">&gt;</a>
        <a href="/search/ajax-search/P280">Last ›</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait until the [ajax load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) request finishes. You can do this by providing a complete callback.

```
$('#search_result')
    .html('<span class="ajax-loader">Please wait ...</span>')
    .load('/search/ajax-search', $("#search-panel").serialize(), function() {
    /* this is your complete callback */
    $('#search_result').find('.paginate p a').addClass('click_paginate');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.paginate a').addClass('yourClassHere');
```

Comment: There's something else in your code that is creating the problem, are you sure that the loading part is working well ?